# Best way to condense several columns of the same data?

Tags: database, ms-access, organization

The question doesn't do the problem justice, so let me try and explain. I'm reorganizing a database which has (amongst other things) 20 fields with tools to be used for a job. Not every job needs 20 tools, some require 1 or 2 or 3.
I was thinking I could grab the info from the 20 existing fields and plop them into a table called tbl_Tools with a single tools field and a key. Then, in the main table remove the 20 fields and add one single field with a reference to the key of tbl_Tools and condense the info of the 20 fields into a single string variable where each tool is separated by a comma (this only has to be done because the location of each tool is important to save). Figure below has a basic explanation.

It this optimal or is there a better way of doing this I'm not figuring out? I'd love to hear your feedback.

Thanks in advance, Rafael.
(Also not sure which tags to use for this)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Book answer to your question would be to use two tables storing separate entries (`TBL_INFO` and `TBL_TOOLS`) and third table which would store connections between them using two foreign keys (`TBL_INFO_TOOLS_REL`), [just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIMD.png).

This way you're minimizing amount of empty columns but also keep clean database without columns that store multiple keys glued together using separators. This allows much simpler management of tools required for certain jobs.

Comment: I've never used three-way table relationships, do forms recognize information easily? I'll give this a go and see how it fares.

Comment: All I can say, it's achievable through forms. Sadly as to how, I haven't used Access in long time and have no way of fiddling with it to give you more concrete answer.

Comment: In Access you can use e.g. subforms. Main form shows the Job (or a list of jobs), subform shows the 0..n tools that belong to the (selected) job. This is quite straightforward and requires minimal code at most. @Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is many to many relationship (this will consist of 3 tables [see the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOUB1.png))
Comma Separated solution would work if your application deals with the logic of splitting and joining tool IDs but this way you lose the ability to query for tool specific data i.e. "which toll was used the most" or "who used tool_3" etc.

Comment: So you're saying if I don't need to query that specifically then CSV would work just fine? As I said to Kacper, I'll try the three tables approach and reply back with an answer. Thanks

Comment: It all depends. Any decision has it's own side effects. On one hand CSV option condemns you to inability to join and lack of future extensibility. On the other you get a simple design and speed improvement(if you were dealing with millions of records). If your app domain is not related to 'tools' I could understand CSV as an additional info kept as something 'extra'. Otherwise 3 tables approach seems like industrial standard.